# Manejo de DOM de manera automática

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Tengo el siguiente código que trae información de la `BDD` en donde automáticamente armo una pantalla modal que contiene un combo *PROVINCIAS* que al elegirse uno de sus datos habilita el siguiente combo *CANTONES*, el mismo que no funciona correctamente

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    ramos_detalles();
  $("#ProvinciaBien").change(function(){cantones_pronvincias();});
  $("#CantonBien").change(function(){parroquias_cantones();});
});
//
function ramos_detalles(){
var code = '<?php echo $negocios['idRamo']; ?>';
var code2 = '<?php echo ($negocios['bolItem'] == 1) ? 1 : 0; ?>';
var vigencia = '<?php echo $negocios['bolVigencia']; ?>';
//
$.get("scripts/catalogos_detalles.php", { code: code, code2: code2 },
  function(resultado){
    if(resultado != false){
      document.getElementById("Bien").disabled = true;
      if(vigencia == 0){
        document.getElementById("bienes").innerHTML = resultado;
        document.getElementById("bienesMov").innerHTML = resultado;     
      }else{
        document.getElementById("bienesMov").innerHTML = resultado;     
      }
    }
  }
);
}
</script>
```

pero coloco una simple instrucción como un `alert('1')` en el código luego de que cargo la función y funciona correctamente por lo que no se que es lo que debo hacer para poner a trabajar este proceso

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    ramos_detalles();
    alert('1');
  $("#ProvinciaBien").change(function(){cantones_pronvincias();});
  $("#CantonBien").change(function(){parroquias_cantones();});
});
//
function ramos_detalles(){
var code = '<?php echo $negocios['idRamo']; ?>';
var code2 = '<?php echo ($negocios['bolItem'] == 1) ? 1 : 0; ?>';
var vigencia = '<?php echo $negocios['bolVigencia']; ?>';
//
$.get("scripts/catalogos_detalles.php", { code: code, code2: code2 },
  function(resultado){
    if(resultado != false){
      document.getElementById("Bien").disabled = true;
      if(vigencia == 0){
        document.getElementById("bienes").innerHTML = resultado;
        document.getElementById("bienesMov").innerHTML = resultado;     
      }else{
        document.getElementById("bienesMov").innerHTML = resultado;     
      }
    }
  }
);
}
</script>
```

Obviamente no necesito que salga una pantalla de alerta en la ejecución del programa.

Si pueden ayudarme gracias por su colaboración.

Comment: Y si pones el alert dentro de la funcion del `$.get` tambien lo ves?

Comment: Tambien esta mal el código de cierre es </script>

Comment: Estimado alanfcm, efectivamente al poner el alert dentro del $.get si se los visualiza, pero al final no funcional las instrucciones posteriores a la funcion ramos_detalle() y solo cuando coloco el alert que indico la ejecucion de las demas instrucciones funcionan, por lo que requiero conocier es si debo de alguna manera validar la carga automatica que incrusto en el div bienes?? algo como eva() para que cargue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que escribes con el alert suena mucho a que tu código no está esperando a que los datos estén listos antes de usarlos, me explico: al poner un alert lo que estás haciendo es darle tiempo a `ramos_detalles();`   de que cargue correctamente los datos a usar en las funciones usadas debajo del alert, así cuando cierras el alert ya ha pasado el tiempo suficiente para que `ramos_detalles();` tenga listos los datos que necesitas en las funciones posteriores que dependen de `ramos_detalles();`.

No puedo tener la certeza de que este es tu problema por que no haz puesto el código necesario para replicar el error así que lo siguiente puede que no te funcione con exactitud...

Cambia tu código por el siguiente, si funciona entonces sigue leyendo, si no porfa pon todo el código posible para mejorar la respuesta:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      ramos_detalles();
      setTimeout(()=>{
          $("#ProvinciaBien").change(function(){cantones_pronvincias();});
          $("#CantonBien").change(function(){parroquias_cantones();});
      },3000)

   });
```

Esta es una  solución provisional, pero no puedo estar seguro porque no se que hacen `cantones_pronvincias()` y `parroquias_cantones()`.

Si tu problema es lo que he descrito y el código de arriba te sirvió la solución mas adecuada es organizar tu código para que solo se ejecute una vez la función asíncrona haya respondido exitosamente, esto se puede hacer con callbacks o  promesas:

callbacks:
En este caso reorganice el código para que solo se ejecute dentro del callback del ajax

```
         $(document).ready(function(){
            ramos_detalles();


        });

        function ramos_detalles(){
            var code = '<?php echo $negocios['idRamo']; ?>';
            var code2 = '<?php echo ($negocios['bolItem'] == 1) ? 1 : 0; ?>';
            var vigencia = '<?php echo $negocios['bolVigencia']; ?>';
            //
            $.get("scripts/catalogos_detalles.php", { code: code, code2: code2 },
              function(resultado){
                if(resultado != false){
                  document.getElementById("Bien").disabled = true;
                  if(vigencia == 0){
                    document.getElementById("bienes").innerHTML = resultado;
                    document.getElementById("bienesMov").innerHTML = resultado;     
                  }else{
                    document.getElementById("bienesMov").innerHTML = resultado;     
                  }
                }
                $("#ProvinciaBien").change(function(){cantones_pronvincias();});
                $("#CantonBien").change(function(){parroquias_cantones();});
              });
        }
```

La forma de hacerlo con promesas la dejo como tarea...

No he probado el código de arriba así que pueden haber errores de sintaxis...

Comment: Estimado clay, efectivamente las primera indicación funciono correctamente y la estoy publicando para los usuarios.... excelente aporte!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que no haya cargado el DOM,
Prueba reemplanzando

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

con
  $(window).on("load",function() {
```

Comment: Estimado Luciano, gracias por tu aporte pero igualmente no funciona a menos que coloque el alert que menciono en la pregunta... 
talvez existe alguna manera dentro de la función que valide que ha cargado el DOM...

Comment: Al estar esto adentro on load deberia cargar el evento una vez cargado el DOM, perdon por preguntar pero no quedo algo cacheado ?

Comment: No hay problema Luciano y gracias por tu interes, lo único que puedo manifestar es que si queda cacheado la información que trae de lo contrario no se veria la ventama modal que llamo para su tratamiento, pero es como que al poner el alert concluye la función y ahí si valida las siguientes instrucciones....